# Using console in localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to use the console in the element inspector for this page localhost/phpmyadmin, after selecting the database in phpmyadmin, the structure tab will show the tables with checkboxes at their left. I want to use a javascript code in the console to automatically check multiple tables in the list, i tried this

```
$('#checkbox_tbl_6, #checkbox_tbl_5').attr('checked', true);
```

to check specific checkboxes, the console responded

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.php, selector: "#checkbox_tbl_6, #checkbox_tbl_5" }
```

and didn't affect a thing

also tried this

```
$('#checkbox_tbl_6').prop('checked', true);
```

and same outcome, i want to use this because i sync our database everyday and only selected table are needed to be synced, it is frustrating checking specific checkboxes every now and then so i decided to use this.it worked in my pc at home by the way but it didn't work on our office

Comment: `length: 0` Your selector didn't match anything.

Comment: is it possible that it didn't matched anything because it is inside an iframe?

Comment: Yes; selectors only match within the current document.

Comment: nice, i opened the database in a new tab and it was not concealed in an iframe and the code worked, thanks

Comment: Can I suggest that you post your findings as an answer (and accept it) so this question no longer shows as open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @SLaks stated, the search didn't match anything in the page. The root cause is that the element that i am searching for is positioned inside an iframe. I loaded the database's structure in another tab so that it won't be enclosed by an iframe, the search worked and i am now able to sync part of my database in a faster way and error free.

```
$('#checkbox_tbl_1').prop('checked', true);
```

I am doing this for almost half a year(syncing selected database tables, looking over a lists of what specific tables should be included over and over), and i am really relieved that this is possible. Preparing time was reduced from 2 minutes to 5 seconds because of this